# problem with codification charset

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding

i have  this example (works in chrome with correct codification, but not in the others browsers)

http://emprego.xtreemhost.com/slide/

how i can solve this? i put the  `charset=ISO-8859-1" for the index and the externals html. The problem is the load() method i think

any help?
ps: already tried with utf8
thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I access `abc.htm` as:

```
http://emprego.xtreemhost.com/slide/abc.htm
```

then my browser correctly guesses that it is encoded as Latin-1 (AKA ISO-8859-1) but it looks like it is interpreted as UTF-8 when you `.load` it. If you load `abc.htm` and play around with the "text encoding" menu (probably under "view" somewhere) in your browser you should see how it appears when interpreted as different encodings.

Have a look at the headers that come back when you load `abc.htm`:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

And `abc.htm` does not specify any particular encoding so it is up to the browser to make a guess. You want your `Content-Type` to look like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

so that the browser knows what encoding it is dealing with.

I'd convert everything to UTF-8 and arrange to have the character specified in the HTML files and in the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code on top of the script

```
$(function() {$.ajaxSetup({beforeSend : function(xhr){xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=Windows-1250');}});});
```